# How do I enable and disable notifications using a switch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications

I'm trying to make a slider so that when it's true it gives you the popup to enable notifications and if it's false it disables notifications for the app. Here's my current code.

```
-(IBAction)NotifSwitch:(id)sender {
if (_NotifSwitch.on) {

    UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert categories:nil];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
}
else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];
}
    }
```

I used the code for the true part in the AppDelegate to show the popup for notifications when you first start the app. Although for some reason it's not working outside of the AppDelegate.

Comment: Unrelated but why do you call the `setOn:animated:` method? The switch will already show the proper value.

Comment: For some reason the app kept freezing when that wasn't their. I just fixed that problem. Let me update the code.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? Remember that iOS will only show the notification pop-up once, it will then keep the user's decision and not ask again unless you deinstall and reinstall the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

of course it's not working outside of the AppDelegate, when your app first start, The code will execute only one time.
you can declare two methods on which contoller you want to switch the state.

```
-(void)switchOnRemoteNotification;
-(void)switchOffRemoteNotification;
```

when the switch turn on, call the switchOn... method, on the contrary, call the switchOff... method.